# Return data from backend function call to front end (Wix Corvid)

Tags: javascript, velo

I have an api request on the backend that looks like this:

```
import Acuity from 'acuityscheduling';

let acuity = Acuity.basic({
  userId: xxx,
  apiKey: 'xxx'
});

export function reschedule(id, datetime){
 var options = {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: {
    datetime : datetime
  }
}
acuity.request('appointments/' + id + '/reschedule', options, function (err, res, appointments) {
 if (err) return err;
 return appointments;
  })
}
```

I want to return `err` or `appointments` to the front end but keep getting undefined.

I've tried

```
return acuity.request...
```

but that only returns the actual request itself to the front end and not the response which is what I need

My front end code looks like:

```
import {reschedule} from 'backend/aModule'

reschedule(data._id, datetime).then((msg) => {
            console.log(msg) //returns undefined
        })
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using request-promise:

```
import Acuity from 'acuityscheduling';    
import rp from 'request-promise'

let acuity = Acuity.basic({
  userId: xxx,
  apiKey: 'xxx'
});

export async function reschedule(id, datetime){
let req = acuity.request('appointments/' + id + '/reschedule')
let options = {
"method":"PUT", 
  "uri": req.uri,
  "json": true,
  "headers": req.headers,
  "body": {
    datetime: datetime
  }
}
return await rp(options)

}
```

Front end code:

```
reschedule(data._id, datetime).then((msg) => {
            console.log(msg)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

I hope this helps someone - there's really not much out there on wixcode/corvid errors like this and it's difficult to get answers on even their own forums. (probably because Wix is a shitty tool to use for something like this, but sometimes you have to bend the rules of nature around the will of your client.)

Comment: You don't need to use `return await rp(options)` just use `return rp(options)`